# Completeness report is incorrect for my education field

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just joined careers today, and the completeness report on my profile page appears to think I have an empty education section aside from the one I entered in. In my opinion, it shouldn't deduct from my completeness score for not actually having another education. Or is it related to having checked "I am currently a student"?

[image: My completeness report]
My completeness report page looks like this.

[image: My education section]
My education section looks like this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It refers to jobs, which ahs been sunset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Somehow</strike> You had created an empty education record a couple minutes before the legit entry showed up.  We have figured out how this happened and it will be fixed in the next push.  I have fixed your profile in the mean time.

Thanks for the feedback, we welcome any more you may have.